# Replace when value NOT this else find value and use?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hoping I can make sense here.

I am working with claims data and a claimant can be either a member on their own policy, a dependent on someone else's policy, or both.

When a claimant submits a claim, the claim is attached to the policy number.

I am trying to get one row per claimant but when I try to join to get this policy number, I am getting multiple rows.

I need the policy number but I also need one row per claimant.

Any ideas on how to best approach this?

This is what I need to accomplish.

```
TABLE1
=========================================================
Claim No.   Policy No.  Claimant    Identity
=========================================================
1           2           Joe         Member
2           3           Joe         Spouse
3           3           Suzy        Member
4           1           Mark        Spouse
=========================================================

TABLE2
=========================================================
Policy No.  Member  E-mail
=========================================================
1           Diane   merp@merp
2           Joe     potato@potato
3           Suzy    fake@fake
=========================================================

RESULT
=================================================================================
Policy No.  Claimant    Identity    E-mail           No. of Claims
=================================================================================
2           Joe         Member      potato@potato    2
3           Suzy        Member      fake@fake        1
1           Mark        Spouse      merp@merp        1
=================================================================================
```

Essentially, I want to grab the e-mail and aggregate number of claims for each claimant. If they are a member on the plan, grab that policy number else grab the policy number for which the claim was submitted.

I don't know if I have enough information to pull this off though. The only way I can think to do it is with the name field but that is not unique (can be many John Smiths in this data for eg.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Common Table Expression to summarize your data from `TABLE1`, then join back to it. (Here, I have taken the liberty to rename `TABLE1` to `Claims`, and `TABLE2` to `Policies`:

```
;WITH ClaimsSummary AS (
    SELECT
      COUNT(*) AS ClaimCount,
      PolicyNo
    FROM Claims
    GROUP BY PolicyNo
 )
SELECT
  *
FROM Policies AS p
INNER JOIN ClaimsSummary AS cs
  ON p.PolicyNo = cs.PolicyNo
```

I made a SQLFiddle with your data, so you can see it live: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2af67/1

---

Some explanation:

- A Common Table Expression (CTE) creates a result set that "belongs" to the scope of the current query. It's like a subquery, but a little different, because it's defined above the main query, not inside of the `JOIN` clause. Common Table Expressions always start with `WITH`, and must be preceded by a `;`, unless they're the first statement in a query batch. (I added the `;` out of habit; it's not really necessary.)
- `COUNT(*)` is what's referred to as an "aggregate function". Aggregate functions group the values of multiple rows together to form a single value.
- `GROUP BY` tells our aggregate function what columns to aggregate on. What we wanted, was "the count of all claims, for a particular policy number" - so we called `COUNT(*)` to count the number of rows in the table (since one row = one claim), and grouped by policy number - this gives us one row in our `ClaimsSummary` CTE for each `PolicyNo`, and the count of each unique `PolicyNo`
- So at this point, we have one record in `ClaimsSummary` for each individual `PolicyNo` - then all we have to do, is `JOIN` the two tables together on their shared key (`PolicyNo`) - and we have what we need.

Here is some additional reading that you can do on aggregate functions - you will understand this answer a lot better if you try it yourself, and aggregate functions are one of the most powerful parts of SQL. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: Wow, how is that working!! It seems too simple. Can you explain how it separates out the coutns in the end?

Comment: @EmmaSmith sure, I'll edit some additional explanation into the answer!

Comment: @EmmaSmith added some additional explanation - let me know if that helps!

Comment: Oh no!!! There was a problem in your information transfer. That's why it's not working for me. INSERT INTO Claims
VALUES
  (1, 2, 'Joe', 'Member'),
  (1, 2, 'Joe', 'Spouse'), should have been INSERT INTO Claims
VALUES
  (1, 2, 'Joe', 'Member'),
  (1, 3, 'Joe', 'Spouse'),

Comment: @EmmaSmith I updated the SQLFiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2af67/1

Comment: Still seeing Joe with only a policy number of 2 :/

Comment: @EmmaSmith - this SQLFiddle replicates your setup data exactly: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bb585/5 - but if you look at your setup data, it shows 'Joe - Spouse' and 'Suzy - Member' on the same PolicyNo (3); so the result set will show Suzy with a ClaimCount of 2, not Joe. Try to edit the SQLFiddle yourself and see what happens - if you make a change on the left-hand pane, you'll need to click 'Build Schema', then 'Run SQL'.